# Den Männern vs Die Männer

Tags: grammaticality, declension, definite-article

So I am reading a grammar book, and there are a couple of tables which seem to contradict.

One table states: "The plural forms of the definite article are the same for all genders," and proceeds to show me:

> Definite article + plural noun: Die Männer = The Men

Further down the same page, there is a table which states: "The forms of the definite article in each case are as follows" and shows:

> Nominative: die
>   Accusative: die
>   Genitive: der
>   Dative: den

With an example:

> Ich will nicht nur mit den Männern arbeiten.

I am confused! Could someone explain the difference between die Männer and den Männern?

Comment: Please tag [tag:definite-articles], [tag:declension]

Comment: @Stephie: I'm too low-rep here to make tag-only edits, that's why I asked one of you to

Comment: @smci urgh, right. Done.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You are mixing up two different things. (Without an actual quote I can’t determine whether the book is imprecise or you misunderstood.)

1. The definitive article has different forms for the cases, i.e. Nominative, Genitive, etc.
2. Unlike for singular, the definitive article *plural* is identical for masculine, feminine and neuter.

So:

> *Nominative*:
>   -  **der** Schuh, **die** Birne and **das** Ziel
>   - **die** Schuhe / Birnen / Ziele
>
> *Genitive*:
>   -  **des** Schuh**s**, **der** Birne and **des** Ziel**s**
>   - **der** Schuhe / Birnen / Ziele
>
> *Dative*:
>   -  **dem** Schuh, **der** Birne and **dem** Ziel
>   - **den** Schuhe**n** / Birnen / Ziele**n**
>
> *Accusative*:
>   -  **den** Schuh, **die** Birne and **das** Ziel
>   - **die** Schuhe / Birnen / Ziele

Answer (score 4):

> One table states: "The plural forms of the definite article are the same for all genders"...

They mean "In the plural of the definite article, **Plural Male Nominative = Female Nominative = Neuter Nominative**". They *don't* mean "Plural Nominative = Accusative = Genitive = Dative", which is obviously not the case.

> and proceeds to show me:
>
> Definite article + plural noun: Die Männer = The Men

Yes, that's referring to the **Nominative** (not the other cases)

The second table is about the declination of the definite article / all cases of the plural, and the example:

> Ich will nicht nur mit den Männern arbeiten.

is an example of **Dative** case